# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064, can't find source

Tags: php, pdo

I'm being thrown an error:

> "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM auction
>   WHERE etime < ?' at line 1 "

My understanding of this is usually I have spelt something wrong where it says the error is occurring.

However, in the following script, there is no `"* FROM auction WHERE etime < ?"` on line 1 of my page.

Further it occurs only 3 times in the page - at line 19, 26 and 288.

I've checked all these locations for a syntax blunder around it and it looks proper. So I have no idea why this is being thrown, I want it to go away.

The page is rather large, bear with me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<?php

session_start();
$url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$_SESSION['lasturl'] = $url;

include("connect.php");

$pdo = connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


    try{
        $old = time() - (60*24*60*60);
        $stmt15 = $pdo->prepare("DELETE * FROM auction WHERE etime < :time");
        $stmt15->bindParam(":time", $old, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt15->execute();

        $time = time();

        $stmt8 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM auction WHERE etime < :time AND closed < 1");
        $stmt8->bindParam(":time", $time, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt8->execute();

        while($row = $stmt8->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $id = $row['ID'];
            $holder = $row['holder'];
            $owner = $row['owner'];

            $stmt5 = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE auction SET closed = 50 WHERE ID = :id");
            $stmt5->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt5->execute();

            $stmt3 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = :holder");
            $stmt3->bindParam(":holder", $holder, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt3->execute();

            $row2 = $stmt3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $fbtokenh = $row2['fbtoken'];

            $fbtokenh++;

            $stmt4 = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE user WHERE username = :holder SET fbtoken = :fbtoken");
            $stmt4->bindParam(":holder", $holder, PDO::PARMA_STR);
            $stmt4->bindParam(":fbtoken", $fbtokenh, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt4->execute();

            $stmt6 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = :owner");
            $stmt6->bindParam(":owner", $owner, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt6->execute();

            $row3 = $stmt6->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $fbtokeno = $row2['fbtoken'];

            $fbtokeno++;

            $stmt7 = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE user WHERE username = :owner SET fbtoken = :fbtoken");
            $stmt7->bindParam(":owner", $owner, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt7->bindParam(":fbtoken", $fbtokeno, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt7->execute();

        }
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
}

if(isset($_GET['searchbox'])){
    $search = $_GET['searchbox'];
}
?>


<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Trade diving equipment online at DiveBay</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery.countdown.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
<script src="js/menuscript.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menustyle.css" media="screen, print" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/searching.css" />






</head>

<body>
<center>
    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="header">
            <div id="hbackground">
                <img src="db3.jpg" alt="hbackground" width="100%" height="100%" style="z-index:1;" />
                <div id="htitle">
                    <span id="banner">DIVEBAY.COM</span>
                    <span id="byline">SEARCHING FOR STUFF ONLINE</span>

                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="float:right; background-color:transparent;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="search.php" onmouseover="setOverImg('1','');" onmouseout="setOutImg('1','');" target=""><img src="buttons/button1up.png" border="0" id="button1" vspace="1" hspace="1"></a><br>
                                <a href="sellanitem.php" onmouseover="setOverImg('2','');" onmouseout="setOutImg('2','');" target=""><img src="buttons/button2up.png" border="0" id="button2" vspace="1" hspace="1"></a><br>
                                <a href="forum.php" onmouseover="setOverImg('3','');" onmouseout="setOutImg('3','');" target=""><img src="buttons/button3up.png" border="0" id="button3" vspace="1" hspace="1"></a><br>
                                <a href="myaccount.php" onmouseover="setOverImg('4','');" onmouseout="setOutImg('4','');" target=""><img src="buttons/button4up.png" border="0" id="button4" vspace="1" hspace="1"></a><br>
                                <a href="support.php" onmouseover="setOverImg('5','');" onmouseout="setOutImg('5','');" target=""><img src="buttons/button5up.png" border="0" id="button5" vspace="1" hspace="1"></a><br>
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])){
?>
                                <a href="logout.php" onmouseover="setOverImg('7','');" onmouseout="setOutImg('7','');" target=""><img src="buttons/button7up.png" border="0" id="button7" vspace="1" hspace="1"></a><br>
<?php
}else{
?>
                                <a href="login_to_divebay.php" onmouseover="setOverImg('6','');" onmouseout="setOutImg('6','');" target=""><img src="buttons/button6up.png" border="0" id="button6" vspace="1" hspace="1"></a><br>
<?php
}
?>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>




                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="searchandlog">
            <div id="search">
                <form id="searchdivebay" action="search.php" method="get">
                    <div id="searchboxholder"><input type="text" name="searchbox" id="searchbox" /></div>
                    <div id="searchbuttonholder"><input type="submit" name="searchbutton" id="searchbutton" value="Search DiveBay"/></div>
                    <input type="hidden" id="submit" name="submit" value="1"/>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="login">
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])){
    echo '<span class="price1">Logged in as:</span>&nbsp;<span class="sessionset">'.$_SESSION['username'].'</span>';
}
else{
    echo '<ul class="signreg">
            <li><i>Existing user?</i><a href="login_to_divebay.php">SIGN IN</a></li>
            <li><i>or, new?</i><a href="createacct.php">REGISTER</a></li>
          </ul>';
}               
?>
            </div>
        </div>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['searchbox'])){

if($search == ""){
?>
    <p style="color:black; font-size:18pt; font-family: Impact; "> You didn"t search for anything!</p>
<?php
}else{
try{
    $time = time();
    $stmt12 = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM auction WHERE name LIKE :name');
    $stmt12->bindParam(':name', '%'. trim($search) .'%',PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt12->execute();



    $numrows = 0;
?>

        <div id="searchresults"><span style="font-style:italic; font-size: 14pt; font-family:Impact;">Search results for: </span>&nbsp<span id="searchword"><?php echo $search; ?></span></div>
        <div id="content">
        <table id="displaying" class="displayer">
<?php

while($row = $stmt12->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $numrows++;
        $ID = $row['ID'];
        $img = $row['img'];
        $desc = $row['description'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $owner = $row['owner'];
        $cprice = $row['sprice'];
        $iprice = $row['iprice'];
        $incprice = $row['incprice'];
        $etime = $row['etime'];
        $nextBid = $cprice + $incprice;

$stmt21 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = :username");
$stmt21->bindParam(":username", $owner,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt21->execute();

$thisuser = $stmt21->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$location = $thisuser['location'];

        echo'
        <tr class="resultindex">

        <td class="imgCol"><a href="displayAuct.php?id='.$ID.'"><img src="'.$img.'" alt="'.$name.'" /></a></td>
        <td class="infoCol">

            <div class="nameDiv">
                <a class="nameLink" href="displayAuct.php?id='.$ID.'">'.$name.'</a><br/>
            </div>
            <div class="descDiv">
                <span class="priceLabel2">'.$desc.'</span>
            </div>

            <div class="userdiv">
                <span class="fromuser">Location: </span><br/>
                <span class="location">'.$location.'</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width:1px; background-color:#330066;" ></td>
        <td class="priceCol">
            <div class="currentp"><span class="priceLabel">Current Bid: </span><br/><span class="price1">$'.$cprice.'</span></div>
            <div class="instantp"><span class="priceLabel2">Instant Sale: </span><br/><span class="price2">$'.$iprice.'</span></div>
            <div style="height:5px;"></div>
            <div class="incp"><span class="priceLabel2">Next Bid:</span><br/><span class="price2">$'.$nextBid.'</span></div>
        </td>
        <td style="width:1px; background-color:#330066;"></td>
        <td class="timerCol">
            <div id="timeRow">
                <span class="timeleft">Time Left: </span>
            </div>
            <div id="countdownRow"></div>

            <script type=text/javascript>
            var timestamp = '. $etime * 1000 .';
            var endTime = new Date();
            endTime.setTime(timestamp);



            $("#countdownRow").countdown({until: endTime});

            </script>
        </td>
        </tr>
        ';
    }
    if($numrows == 0){
?>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="6"><span class="price1">Sorry your search returned no results</span></td>
        </tr>
<?php
    }
    else{
?>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="6"><span class="price1">Displaying <?php echo $numrows; ?> results</span></td>

    </tr>
<?php
    $pdo = null;
    }
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>

    </table>

    </div>
<?php
}else{
?>
    <div id="searchresults"><span style="font-style:italic; font-size: 14pt; font-family:Impact;">Hurry, these auctions dont have long left!:</span></div>
    <div id="content">
    <table id="displaying" class="displayer">
<?php
try{
    $time = time();
    $in15 = time() + 900;
    $stmt55 = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM auction WHERE etime < :etime AND etime > :time ORDER BY etime');
    $stmt55->bindParam(':etime', $in15, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt55->bindParam(':time', $time, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $stmt55->execute();

    while($row = $stmt55->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $ID = $row['ID'];
        $img = $row['img'];
        $desc = $row['description'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $owner = $row['owner'];
        $cprice = $row['sprice'];
        $iprice = $row['iprice'];
        $incprice = $row['incprice'];
        $etime = $row['etime'];
        $nextBid = $cprice + $incprice;

        $stmt23 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = :username");
        $stmt23->bindParam(":username", $owner,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt23->execute();

        $thisuser = $stmt23->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $location = $thisuser['location'];

        echo'
        <tr class="resultindex">

        <td class="imgCol"><a href="displayAuct.php?id='.$ID.'"><img src="'.$img.'" alt="'.$name.'" /></a></td>
        <td class="infoCol">

            <div class="nameDiv">
                <a class="nameLink" href="displayAuct.php?id='.$ID.'">'.$name.'</a><br/>
            </div>
            <div class="descDiv">
                <span class="priceLabel2">'.$desc.'</span>
            </div>

            <div class="userdiv">
                <span class="fromuser">Location: </span><br/>
                <span class="location">'.$location.'</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width:1px; background-color:#330066;" ></td>
        <td class="priceCol">
            <div class="currentp"><span class="priceLabel">Current Bid: </span><br/><span class="price1">$'.$cprice.'</span></div>
            <div class="instantp"><span class="priceLabel2">Instant Sale: </span><br/><span class="price2">$'.$iprice.'</span></div>
            <div style="height:5px;"></div>
            <div class="incp"><span class="priceLabel2">Next Bid:</span><br/><span class="price2">$'.$nextBid.'</span></div>
        </td>
        <td style="width:1px; background-color:#330066;"></td>
        <td class="timerCol">
            <div id="timeRow">
                <span class="timeleft">Time Left: </span>
            </div>
            <div id="countdownRow"></div>

            <script type=text/javascript>
            var timestamp = '. $etime * 1000 .';
            var endTime = new Date();
            endTime.setTime(timestamp);



            $("#countdownRow").countdown({until: endTime});

            </script>
        </td>
        </tr>
        ';

    }
    $pdo = null;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>

    </table>

    </div>

    <div id="sitemap">
    </div>
    </div>
</center>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your SQL is slightly off, you have an extra `*` in your `DELETE`. It would make no sense to give a column list, since `DELETE` always deletes a whole row;

```
DELETE * FROM auction WHERE etime < :time
```

should be

```
DELETE FROM auction WHERE etime < :time
```

Answer (score -2):

> I'm being thrown an error

You are not.

In fact, you are being thrown a way more informative error message, *including the exact spot where the error occurred*. But for some reason you are using the code that strips all the useful info down, throwing naked error message at you.

> can't find source

If you [get rid of these try and catch operators](http://phpdelusions.net/delusion/try-catch), you will make yourself quite informed of the exact query where error occurred.

Comment: How is this supposed to even remotely look like an allegedly useful answer in any kind of possible way? You are just ranting about the question lack of data.

Comment: It actually pretty much says exactly what to do to solve it.